# Batch File Folder Compare?

Tags: batch-file, compare, directory

I am needing some assistance on writing a batch file to pull same file named files from 3 different directories and move those files to mirrored directories.

basically what I am needing is a way to eliminate files that don't have same file names in each of the 3 directories, and then move the ones that do to 3 new directories.

Since the 3 original directories each contain 1 extension type each, 
I'm thinking they could even be moved to 1 single directory.
So basically, Extensions do not matter.

EXAMPLE:

```
DIR1
 -file1
 -file2
DIR2
 -file1
 -file2
 -file3
DIR3
 -file2
 -file3
```

to this: (which would be newly recreated directories)

```
DIR1
 -file2
DIR2
 -file2
DIR3
 -file2
```

Any help is much Appreciated!
THANKS...

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%i in ("dir1/*") do (
if NOT "%%~ni"=="file2" (
del "dir1/%%i"
)
)
for %%i in ("dir2/*") do (
if NOT "%%~ni"=="file2" (
del "dir2/%%i"
)
)
for %%i in ("dir3/*") do (
if NOT "%%~ni"=="file2" (
del "dir3/%%i"
)
)
```

Hope this works.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me...  Keeps telling me it cannot find the files even though the command screen shows them.

Comment: Fixed. I think?

Comment: I don't quite think were on the same page here.  This batch needs to scan 3 folders located in the same directory, for the same file names and move those files (if exist) from all 3 folders to a new location.  Also your help is very much appreciated...

Comment: I have another option - I have a file list of what files I need to retrieve from folder 2 and folder 3.  Now how do I scan folder 1 and folder 2 and get those files from the list and move them to a new folder?